# How to code for exhaustiveness with C++ enum+switch statement

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, algebraic-data-types

#### The question:

How can I get the compiler to warn me when I haven't included a branch for every possible value of a type? This is especially relevant when I am coding with a type that may gain values later (`std::variant` or an `enum`).

---

#### Example:

Here is the code I am playing with (in an attempt to make this work):

```
enum MyEnum {
    ECHAD
    ,SHTAYIM
    // ,SHALOSH
};

int main() {
    MyEnum x = ECHAD;
    switch (x) {
        case ECHAD:
            std::cout << "One" << std::endl;
            break;
        case SHTAYIM:
            std::cout << "Two" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            static_assert(false, "You haven't handled every possible value of MyEnum");
    }
}
```

And here is a godbolt with the following code: https://godbolt.org/z/Kn76q8naq

In my mental model, this should compile. Because every possible value of `MyEnum` has been accounted for. So the `default` branch need not get compiled. That is, until `SHALOSH` gets added to the enum. THEN the compiler should jump in and point this out to me.

---

#### More explanation

> exhaustiveness checking serves as a kind of refactoring tool. Whenever you expand the possibilities in a type, the compiler will point you to the places where you forgot to handle the new cases you just created

For a fuller explanation please see this blog post: https://blog.janestreet.com/what-do-haskellers-have-against-exhaustiveness/ and the talk linked within it.

Comment: Use compiler warning flags: `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and for treating warnings as errors `-Werror`: https://godbolt.org/z/Wz13e8arW

Comment: Realted/duplicate: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: Hello @Yksisarvinen. If you add as an answer: "Use [`-Werror=switch`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)", I will accept it.

Comment: *"So the `default` branch need not get compiled."* All branches should be valid. There is `if constexpr` which allows to discard (dependant) not selected branch which is an exception.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you’re switching on the value of a book and you have a `true` and a `false` branch, then the `default` branch need not be compiled. This is different than a known-at-compile-time constexpr.

Comment: as a side note, there is a library for the efficient ML-style pattern-matrching in C++, https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7